# Change classes in *ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I manage to apply this *ngFor and it's working:

```
<div class="dummy__1" *ngFor="let item of dummy.pic; let i = index"></div>
```

How do I go about changing the `class="dummy_1"` to generate like it is shown below:

```
<div class="dummy__1"></div>
<div class="dummy__2"></div>
<div class="dummy__3"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `ng-container` for the `ngFor` and then use `ngClass` to set the class based on the for loop:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of dummy.pic; let i = index">
  <div [ngClass]="'dummy__' + i"></div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: You could also use `[ngClass]="'dummy__' + i"` without the `ng-container`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use string interpolation for your class:

```
class="'dummy__' + {{i + 1}}"
```

Comment: I've used the solution given by @match. Thank you very much though :)